# Pandas Datetime delta between rows group by another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to calculate time difference in days between the rows when it is grouped by particular column in the pandas DataFrame. The date difference is working only if don't have group by. How do I apply group by and calculate the date difference between the rows? Also below it gives me inverse results, but I want to go from bottom to top for the time difference. What am I missing? Here is what I have tried so far.

.csv file sample

```
group_id,code,date,number
123,abc,2021-02-18,4
123,def,2020-11-11,3
123,ghi,2020-11-10,2
123,jkl,2020-10-01,1
456,gtg,2020-11-28,5
456,abd,2020-10-30,4
456,def,2020-10-05,3
456,jkl,2020-10-01,2
456,uuu,2020-10-01,1
```

My Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('../sample/sample.csv')
print(df)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) # convert date type
```

Try #1: works but not grouped and calculates from top row to bottom row.

```
df['deltaT'] = (df['date'].shift()-df['date'])
```

Try #2: Errors out

```
df['group_id'].shift().where(df['date'].shift()-df['date']) # ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object
```

I am trying to get this result:

```
group_id,code,date,number, deltaT
123,abc,2021-02-18,4, 99 days
123,def,2020-11-11,3, 1 days
123,ghi,2020-11-10,2, 40 days
123,jkl,2020-10-01,1, 0
456,gtg,2020-11-28,5, 29 days
456,abd,2020-10-30,4, 25 days
456,def,2020-10-05,3, 4 days
456,jkl,2020-10-01,2, 0 days
456,uuu,2020-10-01,1, 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
(df.groupby(['group_id'])['date'].shift() - df['date']).shift(-1)
```

```
0   99 days
1    1 days
2   40 days
3       NaT
4   29 days
5   25 days
6    4 days
7    0 days
8       NaT
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

So, you can directly use `.shift()` on the date column for a grouper object **to shift dates by 1 for each group** and then subtract the original date from it.

1. The final `.shift(-1)` (reverse shift) is just to align the results with the expected output on how you have structured it in your question above. If not needed, you can safely remove it.
2. Also, if you need the `NaT` values replaced with 0's, you can use `.shift(fill_value=0)` for both the shifts that you are using.

> **NOTE:** Since you are going to subtract the original dates from the group-shifted ones, please ensure that the data is sorted by (group,date) else it may lead to undesired results!